# mediaplayer dies android

Tags: android

i have a little problem with the media player class. I have a button, and by pressing it a sound will be played. The thing is that there is some delay between when i press the button and when the sound is played, and if i press it too many times the media player dies, and then no sound is played at all and i get the following errors:

```
ERROR/MediaPlayer(3960): error (-19, 0)
ERROR/AudioTrack(3931): AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
ERROR/AudioSink(3931): Unable to create audio track
```

Here's the code:

```
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AssetFileDescriptor afd;
                try {

                    afd = getAssets().openFd("bassdrum6.mp3");
                    player = new MediaPlayer();
                    player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
                    player.prepare();
                    player.start();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

I don't know what's wrong here. I need some help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your going to want to use an on touch listener if you want it to play while the button is being pressed

```
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
b.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (global.toggleOnOff == false) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
               //what you want to happen when they touch the button
            }
            else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
               //what you want to happen when they let go of the button
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I would also use sound pool instead of media player.  That will take care of your errors.  Here's a great tutorial on how to use it. http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=6&number=79

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you are creating multiple MerdiaPlayer objects at the same time (I would expect Android API code should be able to handle this neatly). 
Anyways, You can build a check in your code to validate if mediaplayer is already created. 
See for a good example: 
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.html

Also, it would be better to extend your implementation to release the mediaplayer whenever it has completed it's job. something like a cleanup where afterwards the objects are released.

Comment: well the issue about the media player dying is fixed. But i still get delay when i play the sound. I just figured out that the sound is played when the button is released not when it's pressed. Is there any way to come around this?

Comment: Isn't that because the onclick even only fires after the complete click cycle?